# Automate Reading the SMS Pin not work in digits android

Tags: android, twitter-fabric, fabric-digits

in android app basic functions work fine, but the "Automate reading the SMS pin" function noted in the document is not working.

[fabric-digits](https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/sign-in-with-phone-number.html#automate-reading-the-sms-pin)

Comment: `function noted in the document below is not working` -- which function ?

Comment: Automate reading the SMS

Comment: Unclear what you are asking :)

Comment: in their document they provided a feature for reading sms pin automatically by adding a permission for reading sms in manifest that is not working

Answer (score 2):

First, add SMS permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Then, declare the runtime permission at the time of Login or Use my phone number activity. Add this method to your LoginActivity.class.

```
public static class UtilitiesPhone {
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 130;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context) {
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(currentAPIVersion>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            int permissionPHONE = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
            int permissionSMS = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);

            List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
            if (permissionPHONE != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
            }
            if (permissionSMS != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
            }
            if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                        listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

declare this in your onCreate

```
final boolean result= LoginActivity.UtilitiesPhone.checkPermission(this);
```

And done. Now the autofill works like charm.

Note that you can choose to keep the phone state permission or just remove it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but your code checks for READ_PHONE_STATE and SEND_SMS permissions and Digits needs only RECEIVE_SMS permission...

Answer (score 0):

As per [Document](https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/sign-in-with-phone-number.html#automate-reading-the-sms-pin), you need to add `RECEIVE_SMS` permission to enable Automate Reading the SMS Pin.

> Adding the permission below, in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, allows
>   Digits to read the SMS pin therefore making the login process easier.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

Comment: Post your code in question.  Maybe something missing in it.